# Argument of type 'number | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number' even if isn't null

Tags: angular, typescript

I was wondering why I'm getting this error in TypeScript "Argument of type 'number | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'", because I already tested if my variable wasn't null.

Is there a workaround other than verifying again if my variable isn't null after subscribe?

Here is the example:

```
    if (this.myVariable) {
      this.dialogService
          .openConfirmDialog('TITLE', 'CONTENT')
          .afterClosed()
          .pipe(take(1))
          .subscribe((userChoice: boolean) => {
            if(userChoice){
              this.restFacadeService
                  .archiveBook(this.myVariable) //Here is the error
                  .subscribe(() => { 
                    this.createCustomBook();
                  })
            }
      });
    } else { this.createCustomBook(); }
```

Comment: How about changing this line: if (this.myVariable) into if (!!this.myVariable)

Answer (score 5):

```
if (this.myVariable) {
```

You tested for it, but you did so long before the `subscribe` callback gets called. It's possible that it has changed since then. In general, type narrowing in one part of the code does not apply to callback functions nested inside that code.

You either need to save the value in a different variable that can't change:

```
if (this.myVariable) {
  const saved = this.myVariable; // saved is type number. It can't be null
  this.dialogService
    // ...  
    .subscribe((userChoice: boolean) => {
      if (userChoice) {
        this.restFacadeService
          .archiveBook(saved) // still a number
          // ...
      }
    })
```

Or you need to test `this.myVariable` again in the subscribe callback.